# Proof about partial sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${x_n}$ with $n$ being an element of the non-zero natural numbers be a real sequence and let $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that - if $x_m < \alpha$ holds for infinitely many indices $m \in \mathbb{N}$ - then ${x_n}$ has a strictly monotonically increasing partial sequence.

I really do not know how to go about this. How should one assumption imply the other?

Comment: Which part is confusing to you? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the theorem of Bolzano-Weierstrass. I thought that, as the sequence x_m is limited by alpha, I can just pick a partial sequence of x_m which then is convergent to alpha. I just don't know how to prove that the sequence I picked is strictly monotonically increasing and I don't even know whether the approach I picked makes sense for this problem.

Comment: Please can you clarify what is meant by, " ${x_n}$ has a strictly monotonically increasing partial sequence." Does partial sequence mean subsequence, or sequence of partial sums?

Comment: @AdamRubinson "Partial sequence" must mean subsequence, since your other interpretation makes the result false.

Answer (score 2):

Choose any $m_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{m_1} < \alpha.\ $ Since $x_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\to}\alpha,\ $ by choosing $\varepsilon:=\alpha - x_{m_1}\ $ which we know is $>0,$ by the definition of convergence, $ \exists\ N_1>m_1\ $ such that $\ \vert  \alpha - x_n \vert < \alpha - x_{m_1} \quad \forall\ n\geq N_1.$

By definition,

$$
\vert \alpha - x_n \vert=
\begin{cases}
 \alpha - x_n&\text{if}\,\ \alpha - x_n > 0\\
      -(\alpha - x_n)&\text{if}\,\ \alpha - x_n \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

If $x_n \geq \alpha,\ $ then since $\alpha > x_{m_1},\ $ it follows that $x_n > x_{m_1}.\ $ Else $x_n < \alpha,\ $ and using the definition above, $\ \vert \alpha - x_n \vert = \alpha - x_n. $ Since also $\ \vert  \alpha - x_n \vert < x_{m_1} - \alpha,\ $ it follows that $\ \alpha - x_n < \alpha - x_{m_1},\ \implies x_{m_1} < x_n.\ $ So in either case, $\ x_n > x_{m_1},\ $ and so $\ x_n > x_{m_1}\quad \forall\ n\geq N_1.$

Since $x_m < \alpha$ holds for infinitely many indices $m\in\mathbb{N},$ we can find $m_2\geq N_1$ such that $x_{m_2} < \alpha.\ $ Since $m_2\geq N_1,$ from the result of the previous paragraph it also must be the case that $x_{m_2} > x_{m_1},\ $ and so $\ x_{m_1}<x_{m_2}<\alpha.$

We can continue indefinitely in this way, finding $m_2,$ then $N_2,$ then $m_3,$ then $N_3,$ and so on.

This shows the existence of a monotonically increasing subsequence, namely $(x_{m_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}},$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$